# MERN Stack Auth Structuring

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, mern

I am in the process of implementing the auth services to my MERN Web App. At the moment, I am creating a JWT without expiration on user-creation, and user-logging. However, such a structure doesn't permit removing auth privileges on subscription changes (cancellation, past-due payment, etc). What would be the best way of tackling a seamless flow of User data from MongoDB to the frontend while managing auth states?

Any help is appreciated